# RingCentral select extension user and log them out of app

Tags: ringcentral

Is there any option for RingCentral Admin to log out their extension users from their logged in RC apps.

Example: if there are 3 extension users logged into their RC apps mobile or desktop, Admin wants one of the user to log out from all the app he or she is logged in, how can admin do that for the user?

Can it be done from RingCentral Admin portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is still **not** **there** in RingCentral as of now.
I can see the same requirement is requested as a feature request here in their Idea portal:
https://ideas.ringcentral.com/ideas/CUSTCOM-I-2858

They will review this Idea request and their product team may implement this in next version.